# Solving chain reactions in prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, constraint-handling-rules

[One of the recent Advent of code challenges](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/14) tasks me with solving for the smallest amount of input material that I can use to apply a given set of reactions and get 1 unit of output material.

For example, given

```
10 ORE => 10 A
1 ORE => 1 B
7 A, 1 B => 1 C
7 A, 1 C => 1 D
7 A, 1 D => 1 E
7 A, 1 E => 1 FUEL
```

We need 31 total ore to make 1 fuel (1 to produce a unit of B, then 30 to make the requisite 28 A).

This year, I've been trying to push my programming-language horizons, so I've done most of the challenges in SML/NJ. This one seems—*seemed*—like a good fit for Prolog, given the little I know about it: logic programming, constraint solving, etc.

I haven't, however, been able to successfully model the constraints.

I started by turning this simple example into some facts:

```
makes([ore(10)], a(10)).
makes([ore(1)], b(1)).
makes([a(7), b(7)], c(1)).
makes([a(7), c(1)], d(1)).
makes([a(7), d(1)], e(1)).
makes([a(7), e(1)], fuel(1)).
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure if the list argument is a good structure, or if the functor notation (`ore(10)`) is a good model either.

Then I wanted to build the rules that allow you to say, e.g., 10 ore makes enough for 7 a:

```
% handles the case where we have leftovers?
% is this even the right way to model all this... when we have leftovers, we may
% have to use them in the "reaction"...
makes(In, Out) :-
    Out =.. [F,N],
    Val #>= N,
    OutN =.. [F,Val],
    makes(In, OutN).
```

This works<sup>1</sup>, but I'm not sure it's going to be adequate, since we may care about leftovers (this is a minimization problem, after all)?

I'm stuck on the next two pieces though:

1. I can ask what makes 7 A and get back 10 ore, but I can't ask what is enough for 20 A: how do I write a rule which encodes multiplication/integer factors?
2. I can say that 7 A and 1 E makes 1 fuel, but I can't state that recursively: that is, I cannot state that 14 A and 1 D *also* make 1 fuel. How do I write the rule that encodes this?

I'm open to alternate data encodings for the facts I presented—ultimately, I'll be scripting the transformation from Advent's input to Prolog's facts, so that's the least of my worries. I feel that if I can get this small example working, I can solve the larger problem.

---

1. `?- makes(X, a(7)).` gives back `X=[ore(10)]` infinitely (i.e., if I keep hitting `;` at the prompt, it keeps going). Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your specific question but my first thought on this problem was to use chr in Prolog.

I then thought I would forward chain from `fuel` to the amount of `ore` I need.

The basic constraints:

```
:- chr_constraint ore/1, a/1, b/1,c/1, ab/1, bc/1, ca/1, fuel/0.

a(1),a(1) <=> ore(9).
b(1),b(1),b(1) <=> ore(8).
c(1),c(1),c(1),c(1),c(1) <=> ore(7).

ab(1) <=> a(3),b(4).
bc(1) <=> b(5),c(7).
ca(1) <=> c(4),a(1).
fuel <=> ab(2),bc(3),ca(4).

%Decompose foo/N into foo/1s

a(X) <=> X>1,Y#=X-1|a(Y),a(1).
b(X) <=> X>1,Y#=X-1|b(Y),b(1).
c(X) <=> X>1, Y#=X-1 | c(Y),c(1).

ab(X) <=> X>1, Y#=X-1|ab(Y),ab(1).
bc(X) <=> X>1,Y#=X-1| bc(Y),bc(1).
ca(X) <=> X>1, Y#= X-1| ca(Y),ca(1).

ore(X)<=>X >1, Y #= X -1 |ore(Y),ore(1).

%aggregation (for convenience) 
:- chr_constraint ore_add/1, total_ore/1.

total_ore(A), total_ore(Total) <=> NewTotal #= A + Total, total_ore(NewTotal).
ore_add(A) ==> total_ore(A).

ore(1) <=> ore_add(1).
```

Query:

```
?-fuel.
b(1),
b(1),
c(1),
c(1),
ore_add(1),
ore_add(1),
...
total_ore(150).
```

Then you would need to add a search procedure to eliminate the two b/1s and two c/1s.

I have not implemented this but:

```
?-fuel,b(1),c(3).
ore_add(1),
...
total_ore(165)
```

This has only `ore_add/1` constraints and is the correct result.

Comment: Sorry was using the first example:
 from https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/14
`9 ORE => 2 A
8 ORE => 3 B
7 ORE => 5 C
3 A, 4 B => 1 AB
5 B, 7 C => 1 BC
4 C, 1 A => 1 CA
2 AB, 3 BC, 4 CA => 1 FUEL
The above list of reactions requires 165 ORE to produce 1 FUEL:

Consume 45 ORE to produce 10 A.
Consume 64 ORE to produce 24 B.
Consume 56 ORE to produce 40 C.
Consume 6 A, 8 B to produce 2 AB.
Consume 15 B, 21 C to produce 3 BC.
Consume 16 C, 4 A to produce 4 CA.
Consume 2 AB, 3 BC, 4 CA to produce 1 FUEL.`

Comment: Most probably... but I am not sure off the top of my head how to do it with chr.

Comment: Prob something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655705/defining-chr-constraints-at-runtime

Comment: I'm going to accept this since it answered my questions, more or less, but there will be a follow-up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the example there are no "alternative" path and no multiple "ore sources", so coding the example up in a very non-flexible way using Prolog can be done like this:

```
need(FUEL,OREOUT) :- need(FUEL,0,0,0,0,0,0,OREOUT).

need(FUEL,E,D,C,A,B,ORE,OREOUT) :- FUEL > 0, A2 is 7*FUEL+A, E2 is FUEL+E, need(0, E2, D, C, A2, B, ORE,OREOUT).
need(0,E,D,C,A,B,ORE,OREOUT)    :- E > 0, A2 is 7*E+A, D2 is E+D, need(0, 0, D2, C, A2, B, ORE,OREOUT).
need(0,0,D,C,A,B,ORE,OREOUT)    :- D > 0, A2 is 7*D+A, C2 is D+C, need(0, 0, 0, C2, A2, B, ORE,OREOUT).
need(0,0,0,C,A,B,ORE,OREOUT)    :- C > 0, A2 is 7*C+A, B2 is C+B, need(0, 0, 0, 0, A2, B2, ORE,OREOUT).
need(0,0,0,0,A,B,ORE,OREOUT)    :- X is A + B, X > 0, ORE2 is ORE + (A + 9)//10 + B, need(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ORE2,OREOUT).
need(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ORE, ORE).
```

Then

```
?- need(1011,ORE).
ORE = 3842
```

But this is just a silly and inelegant attempt.

There is a major general problem lurking thereunder, which includes parsing the arbitrarily complex reaction directed acyclic graph and building an appropriate structure. The good think is that it is a DAG, so one cannot generate an "earlier ingredient" from a "later one".

[image: DAG of example ore processing]

Comment: Right, I do need to be able to generalize this. The example was just that, an example. Thanks for showing an alternate attempt though

Answer (score 0):

While making coffee, this is clearly something for the CLP(FD) engine.

If we have directed acyclic graph of reactions with

- FUEL node on the right of the graph and
- nodes for intermediate products IP[i] (i in 0..n) in between, with possibly
- several FUEL nodes, i.e. several ways generating FUEL: FUEL[0] ... FUEL[v] and possibly
- several nodes for intermediate products IP[i], i.e. several ways of creating intermediate product IP[i>0]: IP[i,1] ... IP[i,ways(i)] and
- IP[0] identified with ORE on the left side of the graph

with the last two points giving us a way of choosing a strategy for the product mix, then:

```
FUEL_NEEDED   = mix[0] * FUEL[0] + ... + mix[v] * FUEL[v]
```

with everything in the above a variable

and the following given by the problem statement, with FUEL[0] ... FUEL[v] variables and the rest constants:

```
out_fuel[0] * FUEL[0] = ∑_j ( IP[j] * flow(IPj->FUEL0) )
⋮
out_fuel[v] * FUEL[v] = ∑_j ( IP[j] * flow(IPj->FUELv) )
```

and for each `IP[i>0]`, with the IP[i] variables and the rest constants:

```
out_ip[i] * IP[i] = ∑_j≠i ( IP[j] * flow(IPj->IPi) )
```

in case of a several ways to generate IP[i], we mix (this is like introducing a graph node for the mix of IP[i] from its possible ways IP[i,j]):

```
out_ip[i]   * IP[i]   = ∑_j(0..ways(i)) ( IP[i,j] * mix[i,j] )

out_ip[i,1] * IP[i,1] = ∑_j≠i ( IP[j] * flow(IP[j]->IP[i,1]) )
⋮
out_ip[i,ways(i)] * IP[i,ways(i)] = ∑_j≠i ( IP[j] * flow(IP[j]->IP[i,ways(i)]) )
```

and `IP[0]` (i.e. `ORE`) a free variable to be minimized.

You see an underspecified linear programming problem appearing here, with a matrix having zeroes below the diagonal because it's a DAG, but it contains variables to be optimized in the matrix itself. How to attack that?

Comment: Nah, I'm not satisfied with this idea. This doesn't quite work. Really, this is a problem for Scientific American's "Mathematical Recreations" (does that journal still exist?)